# Replicating Encrypting API key from PHP to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, cryptojs

I have some logic for encrypting an API key in PHP and i want to do exactly the same in javascript, with the same results

```
$api_key = '7#4VBg7ZN3vGZPL4&r3Ow^k4#s2$Q9&NP!ofWJXPP*Tgg05Y05' . date('Ymd');
$encrypt_method = 'AES-256-CBC';
$salt_key = '0Ao10GYe^4EfBYMp';
$salt_iv = 'uV6h%Vl^$u1$vo4^';
base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($api_key, $encrypt_method, $salt_key, 0, $salt_iv));
```

I tried this code in js, but it doesnt give the same result

```
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');

const api_key = '7#4VBg7ZN3vGZPL4&r3Ow^k4#s2$Q9&NP!ofWJXPP*Tgg05Y05' + new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, '');
const salt_key = '0Ao10GYe^4EfBYMp';
const salt_iv = 'uV6h%Vl^$u1$vo4^';

const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(api_key, salt_key, {
  iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(salt_iv),
  mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
  padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});

const base64Encrypted = encrypted.toString();
```

Comment: you're not even using `salt_iv` in the js code, so, chances are that's the first issue

Comment: Sorry didnt copy it correctly, i was using it

Comment: Use a 32 bytes key in the PHP code (or extend the too short key in the CryptoJS code to 32 bytes by padding with 0x00 values). Base64 encode only once in the PHP code (or Base64 encode twice in the CryptoJS code). In the CryptoJS code, pass the AES key as WordArray using the appropriate encoder.